# move target out of bounds: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document. build

Tags: protractor

An error was thrown in an afterAll
build   05-Jun-2018 14:32:03    [INFO] AfterAll Failed: move target out of bounds: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.
build   05-Jun-2018 14:32:03    [INFO]   (Session info: headless chrome=66.0.3359.139)
build   05-Jun-2018 14:32:03    [INFO]   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540471 (9c759b81a907e70363c6312294d30b6ccccc2752),platform=Linux 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

Add the try catch.

```js
function lsTest(){
    var test = 'test';
    try {
        localStorage.setItem(test, test);
        localStorage.removeItem(test);
        return true;
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
}

if(lsTest() === true){
    console.log('presente');
}else{
    console.log('assente');
}
```

This will remove the issue.